# Plesk 12 Firewall blocking VNC connections

Tags: debian, plesk, vnc

I've looked far and wide for an answer to this and can't seem to find one.

I'm running Plesk 12 on Debian 7 and every time I activate the Plesk firewall it times out VNC connections refusing to connect them. If I disable the firewall it works fine, but obviously this isn't something that I want to do.

I've tried adding rules to allow incoming and outgoing connections on port 5900 (as suggested in the Windows docs, I assume it's the same on Linux?) but still no joy.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ahh finally found it...

https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/ai1047203.html

Just in case anybody else is experiencing this problem, on linux, you have to also allow incoming connections on port 5901 ;)